# JQuery DataTable plugin column visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have this JQuery DataTable defined:

```
    APMTable = $(table).DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": AP.APP_ROOT + '/api/'+ AP.WebId + '/' + AP.BillToCompanyKey + '/' + from + '/' + to + '/' + AP.LocaleId + '/' + material,
            "type": "GET"
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "rgNumber" },
            { data: "rgDescription" },
            { data: "rtDescription" },
            { data: "rtNumber" }
        ],
        "responsive": true,
        "order": []
        //"bSort": false
    });

    APMTable.on('xhr.dt',
        function() {
            if (countrycode === 'BR') {
                console.log('SHOW END', countrycode);
                APMTable.column(1).visible(false);
                APMTable.column(2).visible(true);
                APMTable.column(3).visible(true);
            } else {
                console.log('HIDE END', countrycode);
                APMTable.column(1).visible(true);
                APMTable.column(2).visible(false);
                APMTable.column(3).visible(false);
            }
        });
```

I would like column at index 1 to hide and columns 2 and 3 to show if the countrycode is 'BR'. Vice versa if countrycode is not 'BR', of course.

What happens in reality is that the first time the datatable is rendered and the Ajax call completes, the value 'HIDE END   GB' is written to the console, but none of the columns get hidden.

If I then call this:

```
APMTable.ajax.url( '/api/' + AP.WebId + '/' + from + '/' + to + '/' + LocaleId + '/' + material).load();
```

The Ajax event listener fires again and the columns hide.

I'm confused because the console.log() statement is written at the same time the first column hide is attempted, but no columns become hidden. Is the datatable firing a separate event I don't know about after rendering the columns?

Do I need to use a timeout to make the columns hide the first time or is there something else going on?

Comment: I have added a 2000 millisecond timeout to the event listener and changed the event to 'draw' and, after a 2 second wait, on first load, the table does hide those columns. Can anyone suggest an improvement on this?

Comment: Have you looked at the datatable dataFilter option?

Answer (score 0):

If value of `countrycode` is known before initializing the table I would rewrite is as follows:

```
APMTable = $(table).DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": AP.APP_ROOT + '/api/'+ AP.WebId + '/' + AP.BillToCompanyKey + '/' + from + '/' + to + '/' + AP.LocaleId + '/' + material,
        "type": "GET"
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "rgNumber" },
        { data: "rgDescription", visible: (countrycode == 'BR' ? false : true ) },
        { data: "rtDescription", visible: (countrycode == 'BR' ? true : false ) },
        { data: "rtNumber", visible: (countrycode == 'BR' ? true : false ) }
    ],
    "responsive": true,
    "order": []
});
```